# Upload document utility

Tags: asp-classic, document, uploading

I am looking for a tool, either free or low cost, or one I can build myself, that will allow applicants to a program to submit reference letters, resumes and other documents to our organization. We then will distribute as needed. The original submitters should not have ability to share documents once submitted - it is a one way process for them. Only those internal to our organization should have access to the documents once uploaded. I have looked at a lot of file sharing sites but they seem more designed to allow sharing rather than just allowing users to upload.

I hope this makes sense, and that someone can offer some suggestions. We are using ASP on our site so if I need to create something that would be the most appropriate vehicle to do it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this either paid or unpaid, you may want to try [Free ASP Upload](http://www.freeaspupload.net/) or one of my favourites for classic asp is [Pure ASP Upload By DMXZone](http://www.dmxzone.com/go?12064), for the latter you will need to be using Adobe Dreamweaver as it is an extension.

Hope this helps

Robbie

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll take a look and see if they will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The alternatives already listed are great, but in addition check what components your host already supplies one of the upload items should be there such as :

http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/upload.asp

http://www.aspupload.com/